# Windows 10: cannot run WSL (Ubuntu, Alpine, Docker)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my laptop (Dell Latitude 5590,  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz[Cores 4] [Logical processors 8],  BIOS v 1.16.0), running Windows 10 (10.0.19042), I cannot start Ubuntu any more, nor start Docker (Docker Desktop 3.2.2).

WSL version is 5.4.72.

Launching Ubuntu, I get:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8000000d
Error: 0x8000000d An illegal state change was requested.

Press any key to continue...
```

wslconfig says:

```
> wslconfig.exe /list /all
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop
Ubuntu-20.04
```

If I try to Clean/purge all data of Docker (from Docker Desktop's dashboard), or to reset to factory settings, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to terminate distro: exit code: -1
 stdout: There is no distribution with the supplied name.


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<TerminateDistroAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 153
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<TerminateDistrosAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<UnprovisionAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoDestroyAsync>d__32.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 316
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.DestroyTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\DestroyTransition.cs:line 39
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<DestroyAsync>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 90
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<RemoveDataAsync>d__24.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15387\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:line 190
```

The system used to work until few days ago. I don't know what happened (maybe a firmware/OS/software update?).

I already tried the following, but none worked for me:

- uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu (20.04) -> When launching Ubuntu, the error switched to:

  ```
   Installing, this may take a few minutes...
   WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800706be
   Error: 0x800706be The remote procedure call failed.

   Press any key to continue...
  ```
- Attempted to install Alpine WSL: got the same error:

  ```
   Installing, this may take a few minutes...
   WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800706be
   WslRegisterDistribution failed
   Error: 0x800706be The remote procedure call failed.

   Press any key to continue...
  ```
- uninstall and reinstall Docker Desktop
- perform the procedure described at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
- reboot my machine
- verify that WSL and Hd virtualization was enabled in the BIOS settings
- Search for "Turn Windows features on or off" from start menu; verify that "Virtual Machine Platform" was enabled
- run one or more or all of the following in an elevated powershell:

  ```
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   wsl --unregister docker-desktop
   wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
  ```
- Launched this batch:

  ```
   net stop wuauserv
   net stop Cryptsvc
   ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution sdold.old
   ren %windir%\system32\catroot2 crt2old.old
   net start wuauserv
   net start Cryptsvc
  ```
- Uninstalled Ubuntu, Docker, WSL, as described at https://pureinfotech.com/uninstall-wsl2-windows-10/ , reinstalled everything from scratch
- Switched to Windows containers -> got request to run

  ```
   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All
  ```

  Run the required command within an elevated PowerShell -> successfully switched to windows containers; attempt to switch to Linux container again -> no way: Docker keeps running windows containers.
- In powerShell, launched the following:

  ```
  Start-Service "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management"
  Start-Service "Hyper-V Host Compute Service"
  ```
- updated Docker Desktop to rev 3.3.3
- run the following within an elevated command prompt:

  ```
   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
   sfc /scannow
  ```
- Launched:

  ```
   BCDedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Off
  ```

  (also tried:

  ```
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
  ```

  )
- Launched:

  ```
   dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
  ```
- attempt to restart Windows in safe mode and launch Ubuntu -> no luck
- changed Docker Desktop's setting from the dashboard, disabling "Use the WSL 2 based engine" -> docker works with Linux containers! (this doesn't solve the problem, though)
- searched for other solutions on Internet -> none solved my problem

Any suggestions?